# Order MySql results by DateTime value

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to order the results of my MySQL query by their DateTime value which is under column 'timestamp' for each one.

I tried adding

```
$reactions     = DB::query('SELECT * FROM reactions WHERE poster_id=:userid', array(':userid' => $userid));
$comments      = DB::query('SELECT * FROM comments WHERE poster_id=:userid', array(':userid' => $userid));
$mentions      = DB::query('SELECT * FROM comments WHERE FIND_IN_SET(:users , users)', array(':users' => $userid));
$postMentions  = DB::query('SELECT * FROM posts WHERE FIND_IN_SET(:users , users)', array(':users' => $userid));
$likedMessages = DB::query('SELECT * FROM messages WHERE sender_id:senderid AND liked=:liked', array(':senderid' => $userid, ':liked' => 1));
$reports       = DB::query('SELECT * FROM reports WHERE user_id=:userid AND status=:status OR status=:status2', array(':user_id' => $userid, ':status' => 1, ':status2' => 2));
```

But this doesn't order them at all.

**Edit:**

To be more clear; I would like to combine all the results from the queries then order those by timestamp

Comment: Have you tried adding `ORDER BY \`timestamp\``?

Comment: None of your SQL statements includes an ORDER BY. How do you expect them to be put in a specific order without saying what order they should be put in? Seems like you should be looking for a basic SQL tutorial or book before you start working on code using databases. (Rather humorous that your title uses **ORDER** MySql results **BY** DateTime value, but none of your queries contains **ORDER BY**.)

Comment: @KenWhite I do not want the ORDER BY to be in each statement. But what I am trying to accomplish is having the whole list combined then ordered by timestamp, not each statement in ordered timestamp. That is why my queries do not contain ORDER BY because that is not the part I want to order.

Comment: Then you need to UNION the results and then add an ORDER BY (again, a SQL tutorial or book), or populate an array with the results and sort that array. You've posted 6 different SELECT statements, which means you get 6 separate sets of results. If you want them all sorted together, you're going to need to combine them into one set of results that can be ordered. It's difficult to be more specific, because you're (usually foolishly) using SELECT *, which means we have no idea what columns are being returned for each SELECT.

Comment: (continued) The reason that the columns matter is that in order to do a UNION, you have to have the same number of columns in each SELECT and each column has to be of the same data type. We can't tell if that's the case from 6 different SELECT * queries, because * means *all columns*, and we can't see the number or types of the columns each would return. It would be very much in your self-interest to find a SQL tutorial or buy a good book and learn at least the basics of working with data before putting it into your web pages.

Comment: @KenWhite Yes, each table has a different amount of columns, does that affect anything?

Comment: Yes, as I've already said, all tables have to have *the same number of columns that are of the same data type in order to UNION them*. Read my above two comments. (And then, again, find a SQL tutorial or book.)

Comment: @KenWhite Is it possible without union then? Could I do something like add them all into one array and since each has a timestamp, order them by timestamp from the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use order by at the end of your query

```
ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC
```

Comment: That will order each one by it's timestamp, I need the whole list combined then ordered by the timestamp.

Comment: Do a **union** to all your tables then do a **order by**

Comment: I have not worked with a union, how would I implement that?

Comment: SELECT id1, timestamp FROM reactions 
UNION 
SELECT id2, timestamp FROM comments 
ORDER BY timestamp;

Comment: `SELECT * FROM messages WHERE sender_id=:senderid AND liked=:liked UNION SELECT * FROM reactions WHERE poster_id=:userid ORDER BY timestamp` but this will not work because you need to match the column numbers. I suggest you select each table's primary keys and timestamp, do an order by and join all tables that you need. Hope this helps [link](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp)